# How does index on function make query faster?

Tags: sql, database, postgresql, indexing

I was trying to make my queries faster in `POSTGRESQL`. There is a `item` table with columns `price` and `vat`. I wanted to choose items with price include vat higher than, let's say, `x`.

```
SELECT * FROM item WHERE (price*(1+VAT/100.0))>x
```

`EXPLAIN` returned some cost - about 8000.

To make it faster, I've created a function price_vat(price,vat) which computes the same thing (price*(1+VAT/100.0)). When I replaced `(price*(1+VAT/100.0))` by `price_vat(price,vat)`, the execution cost slightly raised (about 9000).

So I've created an `INDEX`

```
CREATE INDEX price_vat_index on item (price_vat(price,vat));
```

Now, when I run the query `EXPLAIN SELECT * FROM item WHERE price_vat(price,vat)>x` it returns much lower cost (about 66% of original).

Does it computes the function on all rows and store them somewhere? If yes, what if I change VAT in some record? Do I have to create a trigger which creates the `INDEX` each time `VAT` or `PRICE` was changed?

Answer (score 1):

When you create an index on an expression, then Postgres needs to "materialize" the expression for all rows.  That is, the expression is calculated for the rows.

The magic of relational databases is that the data remains accurate even when the data is updated.  An update on a row requires recalculated the expression and adjusting the index.

This is why indexes on expressions (or computed columns in other databases) are a tad more complicated than other indexes.  However, they use the same building blocks, and indexes on single columns also often have to be adjusted for updates.